# WPF Button on or off coloured state

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, button

I'm trying to create a set of button which have an off or on state, much a checkbox without the check.  Ideally I want the colour to change to represent the two different states off(red), green(on).  I've tried setting a control template but this only changes the colour for a selection, then reverts back to it's original colour once the mouse leaves the button's vicinity.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Background" Value="Green"/>
   </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, what you describe is a ToggleButton.
Second, use a Style and triggers for "IsChecked"

```
<Style x:Key="MyToggleStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
 <Style.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
   </Trigger>
   <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
   </Trigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

[here is a solution to a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532573/customizing-the-toggle-state-of-a-toggle-button-in-wpf)

Comment: Actually, I think what he wants is not the mouse hover, but the state ispressed. Otherwise, I'm with you on that one :)

Comment: Togglebutton is much better, although the colour still aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

Use something similar to below:

```
<Button>
    ...
    <Button.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeField, Converter={StaticResource yourConverter}}" Value="yourValue">
                    <!-- set what you want here -->
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, could use a CheckBox for that.Allow me to explain :

WPF let you define the control template, which is basically the whole control itself. You could create a checkbox that looks exactly like a button.

However, as someone stated, ToggleButton is probably what you want to use.