# What is a simplest representation of on/off close/open etc. status in wpf?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I'm looking for a wpf 'control' that could represent two states.  The 'control' does not need to take any user input but I'd like to bind its state using mvvm in one direction.  Could someone please make some suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Checkbox or RadioButton

Comment: You could use a `ToggleButton`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532573/customizing-the-toggle-state-of-a-toggle-button-in-wpf

Answer (score 2):

[`CheckBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.checkbox.aspx). Bind [`IsChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.ischecked.aspx), to prevent user interaction you can [disable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled.aspx) it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `ToggleButton`. See [Customizing the toggle state of a toggle button in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532573/customizing-the-toggle-state-of-a-toggle-button-in-wpf) for example about how to style it.

Comment: May be more appropriate for "close/open". CheckBox's probably better for "on/off".