# TreeView MasterDetails with ToggleButton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, styles

I want to create a MasterDetails TreeView with styles.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499016/reusing-a-treeviews-expand-and-collapse-buttons-in-wpf) I wanted to reuse the toggle button

Here is my XAML

```
<Window x:Class="TreeViewMasterDetails.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TreeViewMasterDetails" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="toggleButtonTemplate" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid Width="15" Height="13" Background="Transparent">
                    <Path x:Name="ExpandPath"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
              Margin="1,1,1,1"
              Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
              Data="M 4 0 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                 Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Data"
                  TargetName="ExpandPath"
                  Value="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 8 Z"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
            <Style x:Key="toggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource toggleButtonTemplate}" />
            </Style>


            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}" x:Key="selectedItemTemplate">

                <Grid Height="Auto">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" Height="20" Width="20" Style="{StaticResource toggleButtonStyle}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Id}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <TreeView Height="Auto" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Margin="10" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  Width="Auto"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource selectedItemTemplate}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="x:Type local:NodeViewModel" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Id}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="----"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Please excuse the big block of XAML, but I really have no clue where the exception comes from.

But now I get a StaticResourceHolder Exception with no more information.
I just know that it has something to do with the ToggleButton.

So, there are two questions:

1. How can I find out more about what is wrong with my XAML?
2. What is wrong with the XAML?

Here is my Items ViewModel:

```
public class NodeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<NodeViewModel> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Look at the inner exception. It will tell you further details

Comment: I think the problem is here `{StaticResource GlyphBrush}`.

Comment: @nakiya: and you are right, it was the glyphbrush, thank you very much! but it still does not behave like a default item (expanding on click, but showing the details). maybe somewhat complicated. perhaps you want to provide your comment as an answer, as it helped me out I will accept it.